# Optimising Rails dynamic JSON CPU/memory intensive operations (caching?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, caching, activerecord, memory-management

We've built a dynamic questionnaire with a Angular front-end and RoR backend. Since there are a lot of dynamic parts to handle, it was impossible to utilise ActionView or jbuilder cache helpers. With each Questionnaire request, there are quite a lot of queries to be done, such as checking validity of answers, checking dependencies, etc. Is there a recommended strategy to cache dynamic JSON responses?

To give an idea..

controller code:

```
def advance
  # Decrypt and parse parameters
  request = JSON.parse(decrypt(params[:request]))

  # Process passed parameters
  if request.key?('section_index')
    @result_set.start_section(request['section_index'].to_i)
  elsif request.key?('question_id')
    if valid_answer?(request['question_id'], request['answer_id'])
      @result_set.add_answer(request['question_id'],
                             request['answer_id'],
                             request['started_at'],
                             request['completed_at'])
    else
      return invalid_answer
    end
  end

  render_item(@result_set.next_item)
end
```

The `next_item` could be a question or section, but progress indicator data and possibly a previously given answer (navigation is possible) are returned as well. Also, data is sent encrypted from and to the front-end.

We've also built an admin area with an Angular front-end. In this area results from the questionnaire can be viewed and compared. Quite some queries are being done to find subquestions, comparable questions etc. Which we found hard to cache. After clicking around with multiple simultaneous users, you could fill up the servers memory.

The app is deployed on Passenger and we've fine-tuned the config based on the server configuration. The results are stored in a Postgres database.

**TLDR: In production, we found out memory usage becomes an issue. Some optimisations to queries (includes specifically) are possible, but is there a recommended strategy for caching dynamic JSON responses?**

Answer (score 0):

Without much detail as to how you are storing and retrieving your data, it is a bit tough.  But what it sounds like you are saying is that your `next_item` method is CPU and memory intensive to try to find the next item.  Is that correct?  Assuming that, you might want to take a look at a [Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).  Each node (polymorphic) would have a link to the next node.  You could implement it as a doubly linked list if you needed to step forward and backwards.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! There are some CPU and memory intensive operations indeed. The results are stored in a Postgres database.
I really should have known about Linked Lists earlier in the process, the app is currently in production..
Would the best approach right now be to still implement Linked Lists instead of caching?

Comment: Hard to say, really.  But what I might look in to would be to run a second app server that pre-calculates the results/data and then caches that.  That might be your best bet.  Without knowing your app, though, it is tough to make a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

How often does the data change? If you have can cache big parts of it and you'll find a trigger attribute (e.g. `updated_at`) that you can do fragment caching in the view. Or even better to HTTP caching in the controller. You can mix both.

It's a bit complex. Please have a look at http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/4.0/caching.html